# How to make python learn to subtitute one variable with another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am working on a project and this is a sample doubt from my project

```
a = int(input("Enter Atomic Number: ")
e1 = "Hydrogen"
e2 = "Helium"
e3 = "Lithium"
```

Now, the program must print `"Hydrogen"` `if a = 1` and it must print `"Helium"` `if a = 2`
Note that I must do it for whole 118 elements and cannot use if statements.

Comment: Create a dictionary that maps atomic numbers to names.

Comment: you can try: `print(eval("e"+"1"))`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use some mapping type like `dict`. I Have made some changes to show you example hot it can be solved.

```
a = int(input("Enter Atomic Number: "))
elements = {
    1: "Hydrogen",
    2: "Helium",
    3: "Lithium"
}
element = elements.get(a, "Element not found")
print(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dictionary data structure

```
a = int(input("Enter Atomic Number: ")
elements={ 1: "Hydrogen" ,2: "Helium" }
print(elements[a])
```